# Which Telerik control has been used on this page to display the FAQs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/telerik-premium-collection-for-dotnet.aspx

I want to implement similarly. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The FAQs on that page..when u click on a question, its answer is expanded below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the html source of the page, it appears that telerik use their custom control for that FAQ. My guess is that alike functionality can be attained with the [AJAX panelbar](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

looks like a repeater of panels. you can tell by looking at the url of one of the title links.